# how can i push list style image down?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

i have a list `ul li` and i have set image for it's style. `list-style-image`
but i want the image's position vertically.
it should go more down
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG5aJ.png)

code:
https://jsfiddle.net/zj2x70Lz/

tnx in advance